# Retrieve content between 2 words

Tags: parsing, powershell, logging

I have a build log which I want to extract some content from. I want to extract `[xxxxcontentxxxx]` out of the log file given the system name, if any.

Input.txt:

```
150755: CMDLINE=omake System1
150758: Subsystem Start: Tue Dec 22 03:33:06 2015   1450726386
[xxxxcontentxxxx]
151251: Subsystem End:   Tue Dec 22 03:35:00 2015   1450726500
151255: CMDLINE=omake System2
151258: Subsystem Start: Tue Dec 22 03:35:00 2015   1450726500
151668: Subsystem End:   Tue Dec 22 03:36:28 2015   1450726588
151672: CMDLINE=omake System3
151675: Subsystem Start: Tue Dec 22 03:36:29 2015   1450726589
[xxxxcontentxxxx]
152020: Subsystem End:   Tue Dec 22 03:38:14 2015   1450726694
152024: CMDLINE=omake System4
152027: Subsystem Start: Tue Dec 22 03:38:15 2015   1450726695
[xxxxcontentxxxx]
152294: Subsystem End:   Tue Dec 22 03:39:12 2015   1450726752
152298: CMDLINE=omake System5
152301: Subsystem Start: Tue Dec 22 03:39:12 2015   1450726752
[xxxxcontentxxxx]
152558: Subsystem End:   Tue Dec 22 03:40:18 2015   1450726818
```

For example, I want to extract for System2, System3 and System4. The output should be saved to a file in the following format:

> Note: System2 is skipped because it does not contain [xxxxcontentxxxx]

Output.txt:

```
151672: CMDLINE=omake System3
151675: Subsystem Start: Tue Dec 22 03:36:29 2015   1450726589
[xxxxcontentxxxx]
152020: Subsystem End:   Tue Dec 22 03:38:14 2015   1450726694
152024: CMDLINE=omake System4
152027: Subsystem Start: Tue Dec 22 03:38:15 2015   1450726695
[xxxxcontentxxxx]
152294: Subsystem End:   Tue Dec 22 03:39:12 2015   1450726752
```

How can I achieve this with PowerShell?

Here is something I have. Certainly, there is a more elegant way of achieving this:

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("C:\log.txt")
try {
    $startPrinting = $false
    for (;;) {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if ($line -eq $null) { break }
        if ($line.Split(' ').Contains("System2") -or
            $line.Split(' ').Contains("System3") -or
            $line.Split(' ').Contains("System4")
            ) {
            $startPrinting = $true

        }

        if ($startPrinting) {
            Write-Host $line
        }

        if ($line.split(' ').Contains('End:')) {
            $startPrinting = $false
        }
    }
} finally {
    $reader.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could for instance use a [`switch`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx) statement, like this:

```
$systems = 'System2', 'System3', 'System4'

$reader = [IO.File]::OpenText('.\Documents\test.txt')

while ($line = $reader.ReadLine()) {
  switch -regex ($line) {
    'CMDLINE=omake (\S+)' {
      $systemName = $matches[1]
      $msg = @($line)
    }
    'Subsystem End' {
      if ($systems -contains $systemName) {
        if ($msg.Count -gt 3) {
          $msg -join "`r`n"
        } else {
          "Note: $systemName is skipped because it doesn't have content."
        }
      }
    }
    default { $msg += $line }
  }
}

$reader.Close()
```

This is, of course, entirely unpolished as it assumes that your input file will always start with a `CMDLINE` line and end with a `Subsystem End` line. But it should give you the general idea.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. Your solution certainly is much neater. However, it lists logs from All systems. There is no filtering applied to narrow the log down to specific Systems. Any way to apply such filtering?

Comment: Output only if the system name is in a given list of system names, obviously. See updated answer.